# Easy APNS problem

Tags: ios, push-notification

I am having a problem with Easy APNS . I managed to register the token in the database but when trying to push the notification i get this error:

> Notice: Unregistering Device Token

I did everything like in the video.I generated the pem files but i don't know what to do.I used this tutorial for generating the pem files http://blog.boxedice.com/2009/07/10/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/ .If anybody is familiar with easy apns then please help.Thanks.

Comment: This can occur when you are using the wrong mode (sandbox vs. production). Device tokens are generated differently by the App for each mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that your device is not registered with the apns server you are using (prod / sandbox) so Apple tells you to stop sending alerts to this token.